# Updating DOM Node with text overwrites old text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to write a value into a `DOM` Node. On Start up of the website, the Node is empty, so I do a simple

```
d3.select(`#foobar`)
    .append('text')
    .text(value)
    .attr('x', xPosition)
    .attr('y', yPosition);
```

However, during usage of the website the variable `value` changes its content and I need to append the new `value` to the `DOM`. Calling this function a second time overwrites the current `value`. One still can see the old text underneath... How do I *remove* the old text and append the new?

Answer (score 1):

Before you add the text remove it first

```
var fb = d3.select('#foobar');
fb.select('text').remove();
fb.append('text')
    .text(value)
    .attr('x', xPosition)
    .attr('y', yPosition);
```